# JS - TableDragger is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to import the table-dragger to my front-end, but I get the error-message, that tableDragger is not a function. I tried to go with the tutorial and initialized the table-dragger like this

```
<script src="../node_modules/table-dragger/dist/table-dragger.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var el = document.getElementById("table");
  var dragger = tableDragger(el, {
    dragHandler: ".handle"
  });
</script>
```

With this, the error-message occurs. Anyone had the same problem or has an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Is `table-dragger.min.js` in that location on your web server?

Comment: @RageFoxx  Yes, and the network-tab tells me, that the file is loaded

Answer (score 4):

After going through table-dragger plugins I found that tableDragger is an object instead of a function. You cannot directly get its instance, instead there is a property "default" which actually create instances.

If you are using node then may be "table-dragger.min.js" path is incorrect. The path should be "node_modules/table-dragger/dist/table-dragger.js"

Kindly find below code for reference.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('table');
var dragger = tableDragger.default(el, {
  dragHandler: ".handle"
})
dragger.on('drop',function(from, to){
  console.log(from);
  console.log(to);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/table-dragger@1.0.3/dist/table-dragger.js"></script>
<body>
 <table id="table">
   <thead>
   <tr>
  <th class='handle'>header1<i class="handle"></i></th>
  <th class='handle'>header2</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   <tr>
  <td>conten1</td>
  <td>conten2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
  <td>conten3</td>
  <td>conten4</td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
</body>
```

Good Day :)